# How to work with 3 dimensional word input in Keras

Tags: python, keras, nlp, word2vec

I want to implement a word2vec using Keras. This is how I prepared my training data:

```
encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
sequences = list()
for i in range(1, len(encoded)):
    sent = encoded[i]
    _4grams = list(nltk.ngrams(sent, n=4))
    for gram in _4grams:
        sequences.append(gram)

# split into X and y elements
sequences = np.array(sequences)

X, y = sequences[:, 0:3], sequences[:, 3]
X = to_categorical(X, num_classes=vocab_size)
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)

Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

The following is my model in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=Xtrain.shape))
model.add(Dense(Ytrain.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

Xtrain (6960, 3, 4048)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 6960, 3, 50)       202450    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 6960, 3, 4048)     206448    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)   (None, 6960, 3, 4048)     0         
=================================================================
Total params: 408,898
Trainable params: 408,898
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I got the error:

```
history = model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(Xtest, Ytest))

Error when checking input: expected dense_22_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6960, 3, 4048)
```

I'm confused on how to prepare and feed my training data to a Keras neural network?

Answer (score 0):

Input shape in keras does not necessary imply the shape of the input dataset. Input shape is shape of a single data point in the dataset(shape of input dataset without batch dimension). But you are are specifying the input shape to be shape of the dataset input including the batch dimension. The correct input shape in your case would be `Xtrain.shape[1:]`.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=Xtrain.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(Ytrain.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Comment: It gives the error; `Error when checking target: expected activation_15 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6960, 4048)`